# Publishing and reading files to/from datastore server: scala project

Tags: java, scala, amazon-s3, datastore

We are developing a machine learning framework with Scala. We need a *datastore* to store some data. Here I am explaining the issue in its more general form:

1) Reading from datastore: We have a relatively big dataset which cannot be committed to the git repo, but needs to be stored somewhere. This dataset is not always needed. So somehow we need the program to download the files, when a certain functions in code are asked to run.

2) Publishing to datastore: The system uses a bunch of model files to make predictions. We need the code to publish some output generated files to the datastore, upon running some codes.

I have seen [this](https://github.com/allenai/datastore) based on Amazon S3 ([example here](https://github.com/allenai/datastore/blob/master/datastore/README.md)); although we don't have much access to S3. Instead we have our own servers that we can use. Any idea if there is any tool out there that we can use?

Comment: Tool recommendation question are off topic. And in any case, this is very vague, without any real detail on volumes, structure of dataset, frequency of access or updates, so any answer you'd get would match your requirements only by accident.

Comment: Would you say I add more details or we move it to another forum?

Comment: Move. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, *tool*, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."